# Create literaly a complexe Object in Javascript or Extract objects form an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am currently working on an old website who works only with xslt/xml files.
I try to generate some xml from a "simple" Javascript code.

I am working with an json2xml node module who allow me to parse a Json => xml.

In some cases, i need to "return" in a loop some objects.

```
[
        {name: 'tagName', attrs: { style: 'display:none;'}, text: 'tagContent'},
        {name: 'tagOtherName', attrs: { style: 'display:none;'}, text: 'tagSomeOtherContent'},
        .....
        //here i want to insert others similar objects with a for loop on another array of Objects with variable content/size
        function() {
            ....some magic function who can help me
        }
]
```

Any idea of how i can do this iteratively? 
Maybe some recursive stuff? Or transform my Object to a string then putting it in my object with a JSON.parse?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you might want to just create an element that represents your XML document somewhere in the DOM (just a hidden element) and use the [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) to convert that to XML for you. It might make your life a lot easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` destructuring syntax on the outcome of a function will unpack an array of objects into your list the way you want.

```
[
        {name: 'tagName', attrs: { style: 'display:none;'}, text: 'tagContent'},
        {name: 'tagOtherName', attrs: { style: 'display:none;'}, text: 'tagSomeOtherContent'},

        ...(() => {
            // your function to generate your objects
            return [
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ];
        })()
]
```